# Custom Text Layout CSS-JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I want to do is, I want each row of my text to be shorter (by width) than the one above it. So my text layout will look like my text is inside a upside down pyramid. See the picture below:[image]

How do I manage to do this using CSS, JavaScript, or anything possible?

As requested, here is a reproducible example of the code without the effect:

```html
<div style="text-align: center">Pro. Doç. Dr. John DOE.</div>
<div style="text-align: center">
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin<br/>
literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at</br>
Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words,</br>
Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in</br>
discovered the undoubtable source.
</div>
```

Comment: I couldn't come up with any idea to apply. Any ideas or piece of code is appreciated. Give me a spark to start with, and I'll be thankful :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to give your container element (probably a div) the css attribute `text-align:center`. Then your whole text will be centered in this div. Now set `<br>`-tags in your text to make it break in the desired locations.

Comment: That could work, but I need a solution that doesn't require to add any code inside the text manually. Because the text will be added by visitors. (To be fetched from database and used for a section like 'testimonials' dynamically later on after the admin activates it.)

Comment: This will be a complex Javascript algorithm with many dependencies like font-size, height and width of your container, fontweight. This kind of implementation will be scruffy anyways. You have very few options. Maybe et the creator of your text do the breaks in a textarea.